# Proving $F(f)=\{x\in \mathbb R| f(x)=1\}$ isn't an injection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $$F: \mathbb N ^{\mathbb R}\to \mathcal P(\mathbb R)\\ F(f)=\{x\in \mathbb R| f(x)=1\}$$
>
> Prove that $F$ isn't an injection.

My attempt:

Suppose $F(f_1)=F(f_2)$ and show that $f_1\neq f_2$:

$\{x\in \mathbb R| f_1(x)=1\}=\{x\in \mathbb R| f_2(x)=1\}=\{0\}$ for:

$f_1=\begin{cases}1 &, x=0\\ 3 &, else \end{cases} ,f_2=\begin{cases}1 &, x=0\\ 5 &, else \end{cases}$

So we have $f_1\neq f_2$ and we're done.

Is this enough to disprove an injection?

Comment: Yes, it is enough. Could be simpler functions. Why not $f_1$ identically equal to $0$ and $f_1$ identically equal to $2$?

Comment: That is enough: finding functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ s.t. $F(f_1)=F(f_2)$ and $f_1\neq f_2$.

Comment: I'd just replace the "iff" by a "for", because there are other functions such that $F(f)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Your wording needs some adjustment. You just need to exhibit $f_1 \neq f_2$ such that $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$. That proves that it is not an injection. You can't start with $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$ and show that $f_1 \neq f_2$, because $f_1 = f_2$ **will** result in $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$. A counterexample is sufficient.

Comment: That "suppose ..." isn't clear, to say the least. I'd rather go with "Find $\;f_1,f_2\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb R}\;,\;\;f_1\neq f_2\;$ , but s.t. $\;F(f_1)=F(f_2)\;$" .

Comment: @copper.hat isn't that just the contra positive of what I did?

Comment: @kuhaku Not quite. Your statement assumes that $\;F(f_1)=F(f_2)\;$ will always carry $\;f_1\neq f_2\;$ ,which of course is false. As copper says, one single example will do.

Comment: This is just about wording. You wrote "Suppose ... and show that ...". I'm saying that you can never prove this, because $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$ cannot imply $f_1 \neq f_2$.

Comment: To disprove a statement, you only need give a single example of when it does not hold. The $f_1,f_2$ you defined above do exactly that. No more work required.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The statement "$F$ is injective" means "For any $f_1, f_2$, if $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$ then $f_1 = f_2$." The contrapositive would be "For any $f_1, f_2$, if $f_1 \neq f_2$ then $F(f_1) \neq F(f_2)$", which is what you've disproven, and it's what your math says, but it's not what your text says.

Comment: What is a contra positive? The proof should go like this. Let $f_1(x)=0$ for all $x$, and let $f_2(x)=2$ for all $x$. Then $f_1\ne f_2$ but $F(f_1)=F(f_2)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must show that
$$
\bigwedge_{f, g \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{R}} F(f) = F(g) \Rightarrow f = g \quad (*)
$$
for $F$ to be injective.

You found a case where $f \ne g$ and $F(f) = F(g)$, so the implication $(*)$ is false and thus $F$ is not injective.